# python 3.4 and excel 2013

Tags: python

I am using python 3.4, and I want to operate excel 2013, such as opening an existing file, find the last row and add some value in the last row+1.
Does any one knows how to operate Excel 2013 in Python 3.4? If you can provide a link to download the module or tool, it would be very nice.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Look on https://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=browse&c=533&show=all

Answer (score 4):

Try OpenPyXl.
I believe this is the only library which can read and write Xlsx (as opposed to XlsxWriter) files and is currently well maintained:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/openpyxl/

Here's a link to their official site and documentation:
https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

And here's a simple example from their documentation for reading from file:

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> wb2 = load_workbook('test.xlsx')
>>> print wb2.get_sheet_names()
['Sheet2', 'New Title', 'Sheet1']
```

Edit: For Windows, there also wheels (pre-packaged binary format that can be installed via PIP by pip install some_package.whl) that may solve your installation issues. I generally recommend using wheels (on Windows) whenever possible because they install quickly and reliably.

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 1):

There is an active user group at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/openpyxl-users
That's probably a better place to ask your question.